# Need Value of "sendUserActionEvent() mView == null"

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu, android-actionbar, actionevent

Im currently working on the part of my Android app which should switch between some activities. This happens over the Actionbar Dropdown-Menu.

My Problem is: I don't get any value back to know which Activity i should call (on the if-statements in the onClick).

Heres my Code:
onOptionsItemSelected:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.home) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home wurde angeklickt!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); replaceFragment(hf);
    }
    if (id == R.id.archiv) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Archiv wurde angeklickt!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); replaceFragment(af);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

menu_homescreen(.xml):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@+id/home"
            android:icon="@drawable/home"
            android:title="Gehe zu Home" />
        <item android:id="@+id/archiv"
            android:icon="@drawable/archiv"
            android:title="Gehe zu Archiv" />
    </menu>
```

or is there another way to switch Fragments?
Greetings, John

Comment: sry for noob question. solved it